# Client/server system inaccurate upload to server from client

Tags: java, netbeans, client-server

I am having trouble uploading a file to the server. The server received the file but wont stop receiving once the file is sent. How to make it only receive once? I suspect part of the portion of the server's code that i have included have problem, hope someone able to identify the problem =(

Below is the code.

Client.java

```
 System.out.println("These are the files available on the Server: \n");
String line = null;
while ((line = get1.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);

}
int ans1;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("\n1.Upload a file \n2.Download file \n");
int ans = scan.nextInt();
put.print(ans);
put.flush();
ans1 = ans;



switch(ans1){
    case 1:
        System.out.println("Name the file u wanna upload\n");
        String n=rd.readLine();
        put.println(n);
        n ="Client\\"+n;
//            System.out.println("Requesting "+n);
            //physical source path is added to the name of file 
                File files=new File(n);
                //open the file requested by client on the server machine 
                if(files.exists()){ 
                BufferedInputStream di=new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(n));
                //creates a buffer stream to read bytes from the file 
                BufferedOutputStream outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                //create a buffer stream to send bytes to the client socket
                byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
                // creates a buffer to read from the file
                int read;
                while((read = di.read(buffer))!=-1){

            outStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
            outStream.flush();
            //while file is not finished it reads bytes from the file and send it to the client server
        }
            s.close();
            }
        break;


    case 2:
        String u,f;
        System.out.println("Enter the file name to download from server:");
        DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(System.in);
        f=dis.readLine();
        //it reads the name of file from the user
        put.println(f);
        //it sends the name of requested file to the server machine
        File f1=new File("Client\\"+f);
        //it creates a file with the same name in the physical path given on the client machine
        FileOutputStream  fs=new FileOutputStream(f1);
        //it creates an output stream to write bytes to the file
        BufferedInputStream d=new BufferedInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        //it creates buffer to receive data from server machine
        BufferedOutputStream outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f1));
        //it creates a buffer to write buffer of bytes to the file
        byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while((read = d.read(buffer))!=-1){
        outStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
        outStream.flush();
        //while the input buffer is not finished it reads the input sent by the server and writes it on the file created in the client machine
        }
        fs.close();
        //file is closed
        System.out.println("File received");
        s.close();
        //socket is closed
        System.out.println("wanna cont?");
        int yn = scan.nextInt();
        if(yn == 1){

        }
            break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("exit");
        break;
}


}
```

Server.java

```
 if(num == 49){
        while(true)
            {
               String t=st.readLine();
               put.println(t);
                //it sends the name of requested file to the server machine
               System.out.println("the file will be receiving is "+t);
               File f1=new File("Server\\"+t);
                //it creates a file with the same name in the physical path given on the client machine
                FileOutputStream  fs=new FileOutputStream(f1);
                //it creates an output stream to write bytes to the file
                BufferedInputStream d=new BufferedInputStream(cs.getInputStream());
                //it creates buffer to receive data from server machine
                BufferedOutputStream outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f1));
                //it creates a buffer to write buffer of bytes to the file
                byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
                int read;
                while((read = d.read(buffer))!=-1){
                outStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
                outStream.flush();
                //while the input buffer is not finished it reads the input sent by the server and writes it on the file created in the client machine
                }
                fs.close();
                //file is closed
                System.out.println("File received");
                cs.close();
                //socket is closed
                ss.close();
                s2.close();
```

@Dakkaron here is the front portion of the server code

```
ServerSocket ss=null;

    try{
        ss=new ServerSocket(8081);
    } catch(IOException e){ 
        System.out.println("couldn't listen");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    Socket cs=null;
    try{ 
        cs=ss.accept();
        System.out.println("Connection established"+cs);
    } catch(Exception e){ 
        System.out.println("Accept failed");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    PrintWriter put=new PrintWriter(cs.getOutputStream(),true);
    BufferedReader st=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cs.getInputStream()));
```

Answer (score 0):

A note at the beginning: please format your code correctly so it is easier to read. Most IDEs have a quite decent auto-format-function. Please use it before pasting code here.

Now to your question:
I see your server has an infinite while loop at the beginning directly after the if. From the code-snippet you posted this is the biggest problem I see. So once it finishes receiving the first file it gets looped through to the next file by the while loop.

Try to remove the while(true) in the beginning of the server code and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: but the while loop is for the stream connection.

Comment: Are you sure? This part should be for the stream connection:
    while((read = d.read(buffer))!=-1){
                outStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
                outStream.flush();
                //while the input buffer is not finished it reads the input sent by the server and writes it on the file created in the client machine
    }